Can a cmake build preset run a configuration
Given the following presets construct (not a complete presets file)
{
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "fooConfig",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceParentDir}/build-foo"
    }
  ],
  "buildPresets": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "configurePreset": "fooConfig",
      "targets": "myapp"
    }
  ] 
}

I find that when I try:
cmake --build --preset foo

It fails on a pristine system with error
Error: C:/{..}/build-foo is not a directory

When I read up on build presets, I imagined that cmake would configure and build conveniently from this one command, but I guess that I may be wrong?
Instead I have to explicitly run the configuration through and then instruct the build, like so
cmake --preset fooConfig
cmake --build --preset foo

I suppose it hides away the actual location of the build, but that is of little gain (to me).
So what are the perks of build presets?
Additional information
The same question was asked on the cmake forum, but the person answering didn't truly understand what the OP was asking.

Without presets, a single cmake run may either configure or build the project, but cannot do not both. Presets doesn't change core aspects of CMake.

It would be a massive win for cmake if it did. No person or script would need to learn the build directory, nor the name of the cmake config preset. Only the name of the build preset, which can be gleaned though cmake --list-presets=build. Shame, but it is what it is.

It appears that workflow presets could be of benefit here.


Can a cmake build preset run a configuration

No.

what are the perks of build presets?

From https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html :

One problem that CMake users often face is sharing settings with other people for common ways to configure a project. This may be done to support CI builds, or for users who frequently use the same build. CMake supports two main files, CMakePresets.json and CMakeUserPresets.json, that allow users to specify common configure options and share them with others. CMake also supports files included with the include field.


You're just quoting from the brochure, which describes CMake presets as a whole. This question is specifically about a build presets, which is a sub-part of cmake presets. The quoted paragraph does not enlighten me. Nor does Kitware's documentation on build presets for that matter.

Hi. I do not understand. Yes, I agree with the first two sentences. In what way did you expect to be "enlightened"? The build presets "sub-part" of cmake presets has the same "perks" as cmake presets as a whole, because it is a "sub-part" of cmake presets, exactly you noted. I do not follow. Is there a distinction? Should it be different? I wil totally agree quoting the documentation is "low-effort", but it has been my experience many stackoverflow askers do not check documentation at all.

It's not clear (again, to me) what build presets bring to the table. With just config presets, or with config presets and build presets, the process is evidently still two-staged, both needing two parts of the puzzle. Either it is [config name, build dir] (config presets only) or it is [config name, build name] (config presets and build presets).

The only thing I can think of (and it could just be that reason for build presets to exist?) is that a build preset can single out specific targets for a CMakeLists.txt, whereas if you use only the config presets then it would build all targets (unless you use the --target CL option ofc)

You can set environment variables and set verbosity and cleanFirst flags to share the configuration between developers and CI/CD environments. Is it not "unify" tool, it is "share" tool, to keep your command line options in one place.


So what are the perks of build presets?

The main utility of build presets is to share particular build configurations within the sources of the project without resorting to writing a build.sh script or similar.
But I think what you are looking for are Workflow Presets (introduced with CMake 3.25), that allow you to declare a sequence of steps, configure then build for example:
{
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "fooConfig",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceParentDir}/build-foo"
    }
  ],
  "buildPresets": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "configurePreset": "fooConfig",
      "targets": "myapp"
    }
  ],
  "workflowPresets": [
    {
      "name": "fooWorkflow",
      "steps": [
        {
           "type": "configure",
           "name": "fooConfig"
        },
        {
          "type": "build",
          "name": "foo"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

And then you use it by running
cmake --workflow --preset fooWorkflow

It configures your project, then builds it.
Hope this helps!
